# How do I add 1 to a SQLite3 Integer (python)

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, upsert

I am trying to make a table that logs the amount of times a player has logged in, by UUID and number of joins.

[Here is what my table looks like (for testing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWrc4.png)

I would like to make my program check if the UUID is already in the database, and then add **1** to the number of joins.

```py
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("joins.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE joinsdatabase (uuid TEXT, joins INTEGER)")
except:
    print("Table exists: Not creating a new one!")

def addP(player_uuid):
    rows = cursor.execute("SELECT uuid, joins FROM joinsdatabase").fetchall()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO joinsdatabase VALUES ('"+player_uuid+"', 1)")
    connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.24.0+ you can use `UPSERT`, but first you must define the column `uuid` as `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE`.
So drop the table that you have with:

```
DROP TABLE joinsdatabase;
```

and then recreate it:

```
CREATE TABLE joinsdatabase (uuid TEXT PRIMARY KEY, joins INTEGER DEFAULT 1)
```

This way also, the default value of `joins` for a new row will be 1, so there is no need to set it in the `INSERT` statement.

Now you can use `UPSERT` like this:

```
def addP(player_uuid):
    sql = """INSERT INTO joinsdatabase(uuid) VALUES (?)
    ON CONFLICT(uuid) DO UPDATE
    SET joins = joins + 1"""
    cursor.execute(sql, (player_uuid,))
    connection.commit()
```

You don't need this line:

```
rows = cursor.execute("SELECT uuid, joins FROM joinsdatabase").fetchall()
```

inside `addP()`.

If your version of SQLite does not support `UPSERT` you will need 2 statements.

```
def addP(player_uuid):
    sql = "UPDATE joinsdatabase SET joins = joins + 1 WHERE uuid = ?"
    cursor.execute(sql, (player_uuid,))
    sql = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO joinsdatabase(uuid) VALUES (?)"
    cursor.execute(sql, (player_uuid,))
    connection.commit()
```

The `UPDATE` statement will update the row if the `uuid` exists in the table and the `INSERT` statement will insert the row if the `uuid` does not exist in the table.
This will also work if `uuid` is unique.

Comment: cursor.execute(sql, (player_uuid,)) throws this error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/super/Desktop/leaderboards.py", line 23, in <module>
    addP("anothertesttt")
  File "C:/Users/super/Desktop/leaderboards.py", line 19, in addP
    cursor.execute(sql, (player_uuid,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ON": syntax error

Comment: Check the version of SQLite that you have. UPSERT works if it is 3.24.0+

Comment: I am running 3.33.0, but I think I put my code in an incorrect order, could you put it in a hastebin so that I can see what I need to do?

Comment: "ON CONFLICT(uuid) DO UPDATE" causes this error : sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ON": syntax error

Comment: This is why I believe that the version that you actually use is prior to 3.24.0. Check this answer to get the version.

Comment: Check my edited answer for a solution for prior versions of SQLite.

Comment: This code seems to work, but it keeps the previous one there, creating [('anothertesttt', 4), ('anothertesttt', 3), ('anothertesttt', 2), ('anothertesttt', 1)]

Comment: Did you drop the original table and recreate it with uuid as primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you may need to play about with the variables.

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE joinsdatabase SET count = ? WHERE uuid = ?", (int(oldCount) + 1, player_uuid))
```

Comment: What is `oldCount`? Also, if the uuid does not exist in the table, this query will not insert it in the table.